# Copying list to new list still change the old list's value

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

I have taken a list into property:

```
public List<Pair> PairList {get;set;}
```

and its value getting set from some functions and then I have copied this list to another list:

```
List<Pair> newPairList =new List<Pair>(PairList);
```

I have used newPairList in some function which sets some value in newPairList

```
somefunc(newPairList)
{
 newPairList.stringVal ="xxxxx";
}

public class Pair
{
    public int intVal;
    public string key;
    public string stringVal;
    public string ValType;

    public Pair(string key, int val);
    public Pair(string key, string val);

}
```

Actual problem:
If anything gets updated in newPairList, it will automatically gets updated in PairList. how to prevent main property **PairList** not getting updated?

Comment: Create new Pair objects, f.e. by providing a `DeepCopy` function that returns it. Then you could get the list with: `List<Pair> newPairList=PairList.Select(p => p.DeepCopy()).ToList();`

Comment: Since Pair is a reference type, your new list will hold references to the same objects referenced by the references in the old list. The only thing you can do is to clone the instances if the Pair class inside the first list into new instances and populate the second list with these new instances.

Comment: @ZoharPeled can you able to provide some code. that will help a lot

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper look at the answers you already have... I was starting to write an answer but René Vogt was faster then me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Pair` type is a `class`. So in your `List<Pair>` you store **references** to the instances of `Pair`.

So if you instantiate a `Pair`

```
Pair pair = new Pair();
```

`pair` has a reference. If you add that reference to a `List<Pair>`

```
PairList.Add(pair);
```

and then copy this list into another one

```
newPairList = new List<Pair>(PairList);
```

you copy the *references* to the new list. And if you change the properties of the instances *referenced* in the new list, it's still the same references. So you change the original `Pair` instance.

---

What you want to do is to **copy the `Pair` instances** instead:

```
newPairList = PairList.Select(p => new Pair(p.key, p.intval) {
                         stringVal = p.stringVal,
                         ValType = p.ValType
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: your answer seems to close, but  I have one concern. Loot at the class value where stringval is also there and I had combination of two diff constructor as well

Comment: Addition to that Class Pair comes from third party dll and I cant put interface implementation of Iclonable

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper you dont need to implement Icloneable here. this way should work fine without any changes to `Pair` class. i deleted my answer.

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper As kazem stated, IClonable is not necessary, and you can use one of the constructors as I show in my updated answer.

Comment: @RenéVogt I have tried to copy+paste your code and it is throwing a compile time error: does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: @RenéVogt your internet seems fast and smart. sorry my comments were before the updated code. let me try with new solution

Comment: @RenéVogt yaaaay its worked like charm !!!! many thanks.
just a question from where you learned this kind of stuffs?? :P

Comment: Actually it's basic c# knowledge (no offence, we've all been there). and a lot of years of experience.