# Convert all C# Hashtable values and ArrayList values into strings

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist, hashtable

My input is a HashTable with integer keys and integer values. I want to convert all the integer values into string values. So the output would be a HashTable of integer keys and string values.

Likewise for ArrayLists. I have an ArrayList with all integers and I want the output to be an ArrayList of all strings.

My approach was to loop through and convert each entry in the Hashtable and ArrayList but I feel like there's an easier way to do this without loops. I was thinking something along the lines of using LINQ?

**UPDATE:**

If it were up to me, I'd avoid HashTables and ArrayLists altogether lol but that's another story. The reason why I need to convert each value into a string is because I have a complex object (Car) that contains a Hashtable property and Arraylist property. The Hashtable/Arraylist values are other complex objects.
I'm sending "Car" objects over from a client application to a WebAPI so "Car" gets converted into JSON. The annoying thing is when I try to deserialize "Car" from the WebAPI. Everything gets deserialized except for the Hashtable/Arraylist values. The values are still in JToken format and I'd have to convert them into strings one by one via a loop.

Comment: do you have any evidence of your try, why not a datatype as per your requirement instead for this conversion? I mean a `HashTable` of integer keys and string values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298121/copying-list-to-new-list-still-change-the-old-lists-value

Comment: There no easy way without loop. You need loop all values anyway. Even with LINQ. You need create new instances of `Hashtable<int, string>` and `ArrayList<string>`

Comment: What you want to do doesn't make sense, since both containers only contain objects.  There is no constructor/extension that allows them to be declared with a type.  Therefore if you want to use them as their base types you have to cast them anyway.  Since you only want to convert to strings, just call the `ToString()` method, whenever you want a string

Comment: @un-lucky: See my update for why I need to do this. I agree that I shouldn't need to do this but that's another story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ if you are OK to change from a `Hashtable` to a `Dictionary` and from an `ArrayList` to a `List` (which you should do anyway since you are boxing every value in your hashtable and array list):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = hashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(entry => (int)entry.Key, entry => entry.Value.ToString());

List<string> list = arrayList.Cast<int>().Select(value => value.ToString()).ToList();
```